# Disable Default Keyboard when Click/Touch EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-input-method

I created my own keyboard and I want to show it when the user clicks/touches the `EditText`. I googled the issue and tried several ways to make it; however, none of them worked for me. Also, I did not find any mistakes if I made some in the code. So here is the code lines:

```
minText = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.minLetField );
        minText.setOnTouchListener( new OnTouchListener()
        {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CLICKED-MIN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                getWindow().setSoftInputMode( WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

                return false;
            }
        });
```

When I run the app, the toast message appears but the keyboard does not hide. Also I tried it in `clickListener` like that:

```
minText.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                isMinTextField = true;

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CLICKED-MIN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                getWindow().setSoftInputMode(LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
                //enableKeyboard();
            }
        });
```

But it gave the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `setInputType(0);` solves the problem.